# How do I change seed/database settings in PlayMorphia between dev and prod?

Tags: playframework, morphia

I have a Play Framework (1.2.4) project with PlayMorphia that has two different database connection profiles. One is for development and the other is for production, but I am only seeing one static looking config file hosting the values.

I am reading on how this all works, but struggling on how to support two configuration settings. Is there some configuration trick in Play that people use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose you have

```
morphia.db.name=test
```

Now add one more line:

```
%prod.morphia.db.name=prod
```

And start your application:

```
play start --%prod
```

Comment: Ah, that's cool. Thank you for that. I was also wondering about how to run prod command line as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines in your application.config file

```
morphia.db.seeds="127.0.0.1:27017"
%prod.morphia.db.name=production_db_name
morphia.db.name=mobilereal_dev
```